# Как можно запустить ServiceMix с помощью IDEA?

Tags: apache

Как можно запустить ServiceMix с помощью IDEA?

Comment: Возможно этот ответ с англоязычного SO будет вам полезен: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8037084/2506123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Linux

1. Установите плагин BashSupport
2. Откройте редактирование конфигураций (Run -> Edit Configurations...).
3. Добавьте новую конфигурацию - Bash
4. Укажите имя для новой конфигурации и место расположение `servicemix`

Для Widnows

1. Установите плагин Batch Script Support
2. Откройте редактирование конфигураций (Run -> Edit Configurations...).
3. Добавьте новую конфигурацию - Batch
4. Укажите имя для новой конфигурации и место расположение `servicemix.bat`

Полсе этих действий у вас появится конфигурация которая будет запускать ServiceMix.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо!